# Count duplicated words in a text file

Tags: 12.04, command-line, find

I have a 20 mb file with text and ids. I need a grep or something to count and show any duplicated ids.

Comment: Post an example of the text and id format - one or two entries.

Comment: id-s are in a json array and that's how this looks `"code": ["590702HV-16", "590702HV-17", "590702HV-18", "590702HV-19", "590702HV-20", "590702HV-21", "590702HV-23"], "name": ["Pandora Silver Bracelet  From"], "descr": ["<span class=\"Label33\"><br><font size=\"2\"><font face=\"Verdana\"><span style=\"font-weight: bold;\">Pandora Bracelet\u00a0\u00a0\u00a0\u00a0\u00a0\u00a0\u00a0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk '{print $2}' file_name | sort | uniq -c | sort -n | awk '$1>1 {print $2}' > duplicates
for x in $(< duplicates); do grep -n $x file;
done
```

so there if you have the ID's in the second column then it will print out the Duplicates ID's

Note: In the file_name ,place your file name .

Comment: Based on your „uniq” idea, it could have been: `awk '{print $2}' file_name | sort | uniq -d`.